# Error mounting with exit code 1

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

Error mounting: `mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with: mount: only root can mount /dev/sda5 on /media/bakwas`

```
/etc/fstab: static file system information.

<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

/dev/sda7   /host   fuseblk defaults,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096    0   0
/dev/sda6   /media/New_Volume   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8     0   0
/dev/sda1   /media/SYSTEM   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8     0   0
/dev/sda5   /media/bakwas   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8     0   0
/dev/sda2   /media/windows7_64bit   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8     0   0
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk    none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Above is my fstab file.

I am not able to understand how to solve this problem. Please help me. I am new in LINUX

When I am restarting system it is showing me all my drives already mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Debian and it's children, one of which is Ubuntu, use the [RootSudo approach](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).  As such, since only root can mount drives, your command should be:

```
sudo mount -v /media/bakwas
```